# array in tostring Convert type char to string

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, frameworks

I have this code,but getting some error.after that i change the code.but i wanted to know is that correct.

```
 modifiedMessage = convertToISOfromUtf8(modifiedMessage, "ISO8859-1", "UTF-8");

        char[] characters_to_removed_from_start = { ' ' };
        modifiedMessage = modifiedMessage.TrimStart(characters_to_removed_from_start);

        String msg_arr = modifiedMessage.Split(' ');

        String keyword = msg_arr[0];

        //Linq
        if (keyword != null)
        {
            string[] key = Regex.Split(msg_arr, @keyword).Skip(0).ToArray();
          //  message_in = String.Join(message_in,key);
            message_in = String.Join(msg_arr, key);

            modifiedMessage="";

        }
```

Those are Errors shown
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'
Error   2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'string'

Then i change my code like this..(Only changed code listed below)

```
 String msg_arr = modifiedMessage.Split(' ').ToString();

 String keyword = msg_arr[0].ToString();
```

I wanted to know my works is Correct ?

Answer (score 1):

No, thats not correct, change

```
String msg_arr = modifiedMessage.Split(' ');
```

to

```
String[] msg_arr = modifiedMessage.Split(' ');
```

this will resolve "Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'"

and Error 2 dissapears also

Answer (score 0):

Declare the **msg_arr** variable as `string[]` or as `var`.

Your syntax is not compliant to .NET and C# [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0.aspx), use [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com) to have an help.